# Instalar Fusion Inventory por GPO , ejecutando el .exe como administrador de red a través de un Script .bat o Ps1

Tags: windows, batch, powershell, directorioactivo

Alguien me podria ayudar, cree una **GPO** para ejecutar un **.bat** que ejecuta un **.exe** con comandos de instalación, pero tengo el problema que la politica de la empresa, evita que se ejecuten .exe sin permisos administrador, por lo cual , aunque aplique la GPO exitosamente, el .exe no se ejecuta y no se hace la instalación que quiero. La GPO replica en otros servidores de GPO para que se ejcuten en otras locaciones con muchos desktop.

Script:

> \MTAD300\Util\Finventory\fusioninventory-agent_windows-x64_2.4.2.exe /debug=1 /acceptlicense /server='https://ayuda.servidor.com/plugins/fusioninventory' /delaytime=60 /execmode=service /add-firewall-exception /installtasks=full /runnow /S

Cuando ejecuto manualmente el **.bat** como administrador si se instala todo bien, lo ejecuto con un usuario sin privilegios y no se ejecuta el .exe (logicamente), lo que quiero es que se pueda ejecutar, no se si hay una opcion a través de un comando en el que escriba un parametro el usuario y contraseña de administrador para ejecutarlo, igual el script al tener `/S` se ejecutara en modo silencioso.

***Update 23/4/2019***

**Opcion 1:**

Run as disabled:(FAIL)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjjL3.png]

**Opcion 2:**

Parameters script:(FAIL)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdYzY.png]

**Opcion 3:**

Script Powershell, ejecutar script para que ejecute .bat con privilegios y rellene el user account control: (FAIL, falta de conocimeinto en prowershell powershell)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIxYb.png]

**Opcion 4:**

...Please HELP-ME...

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre de la siguiente manera:

*Descargué el agente de **FusionInventory en 32 BITS** desde:

https://github.com/fusioninventory/fusioninventory-agent/releases/download/2.5/fusioninventory-agent_windows-x86_2.5.exe

***(Si tienes un ecosistema Microsoft 100% en 64 bits, puedes desplegar el agente de 64 bits, en vez de 32... En mi caso, contaba con un ecosistema híbrido con máquinas tanto en 32 como en)***

*Renombré el archivo descargado como **agente32.exe**, lo alojé en una carpeta compartida (creo que fue en el controlador de dominio, algo como `\\192.168.5.21\sysvol\agente32.exe`, actualmente carezco de acceso para verificar la ruta)

*Cree en el Dominio la **POLITICA de EQUIPO** que se observa en la imagen adjunta. Instalación **FUSIONINVENTORY** como Política de Grupo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de lo anterior las máquinas instalarán el agente bajo las siguientes 4 circunstancias:

1. Al ser vinculadas por primera vez al dominio
2. Si carece de agente, en el próximo reinicio
3. Si carece de agente, al ejecutar `gpupdate /force` en la máquina
4. Una vez instalado el agente FUSIONINVENTORY, la labor de Inventario NO se ejecuta inmediatamente (el algoritmo de instalación agenda el inventario para una hora aleatoria). Por tal motivo, al instalar el agente FUSIONINVENTORY las máquinas NO aparecerán inmediatamente en GLPI. Solo tienes que esperar 24 horas, en el transcurso de las cuales el agente disparará una labor de inventario automática y las máquinas comenzarán a aparecer en GLPI.

No hizo falta tanto script, obviamente se podria pulir el funcionamiento, pero asi funciono y logre el objetivo buscado.

Solo me falta que los usuarios a totalidad reinicien su equipo para que aplique la GPO a todos -.- , dejan los equipos encendidos siempre y no se ha aplicado a todos.

Intente con `shutdown -i`, pero no me deja agregar una OU entera y aplicar una GPo de reinicio no tiene logica ya que intento que aplique una GPO. jeje.

Parte de la ayuda la investigue y recibí ayuda de:

https://juliorestrepo.wordpress.com